# Find a point in an ellipse from its standard equation and the distances from the focal point

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I know it may sound stupid, but I'm really struggling with that.

I remember to have seen something like these in my descriptive geometry classes, but i can't remember how I can manage to that.

I have the standard equation of an ellipse with center at the origin, and I have the focal distances to a point(I know that there is two possibilities) in this ellipse, I need to know the x and y coordinates of those poins.

So far the path I'm going is something like that:

$D_1=\sqrt{{(x-x_1)}^2+{(y-y_1)}^2}\qquad\qquad$  **(1)**

$D_2=\sqrt{{(x-x_2)}^2+{(y-y_2)}^2}\qquad\qquad$ **(2)**

$L=D_1+D_2\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;$ **(3)**

$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;\;$ **(4)**

Again, I know $D_1$, $D_2$, $a$ and $b$, so I squared eq.1,2 and 3 and plug eq.1 and eq.2 in eq.3:

**THIS IS WRONG**

${(x-x_1)}^2+{(y-y_1)}^2+{(x-x_2)}^2+{(y-y_2)}^2=L^2\qquad\qquad$ **(5)**

Then I tried to solve for $y$ and $y^2$ in eq.4 and plug in the eq.5 but I didn't manage to deal with the sqrt.

Any thought or easier ways of solving?

Comment: $D_1^2+D_2^2\ne L^2=(D_1+D_2)^2$. That aside, working with equation (3) is just going to get you back to the equation of the ellipse.

Comment: Since you know $a$ and $b$, then presumably you also know or can find the coordinates of the foci. The problem then becomes one of intersecting a circle with the ellipse.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was missing, and thanks again for the correction on eq.3

Comment: Intersecting a circle with the ellipse in general can have four solutions, so it's a quartic polynomial.  I believe we can do better here using the special form of the two polynomials to get a quadratic to solve, but I haven't worked out the details.

Comment: @Sure. Just based on the geometry here, you’re guaranteed to have exactly two real roots (perhaps repeated). That suggests that the solution reduces to solving a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance between foci is $2c$ where $c^2 = a^2 - b^2.$
So you should quickly be able to find the coordinates of the two foci:
$(x_1,y_1) = (c,0)$ and $(x_2,y_2) = (-c,0).$

Now if you also know $D_1$ and $D_2$ which are the distances from the foci
$(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ (respectively) to the unknown point $(x,y),$
then

\begin{align}
D_1^2 &= (x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2, \tag1 \\
D_2^2 &= (x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2. \tag2
\end{align}

Note that you already had these equations, except that your version gives the square root of each side, which turns out not to be very helpful. (Your idea to square both $D_1$ and $D_2$ was a good one, you just need to apply it better.)

You can plug the known coordinates $(x_1,y_1) = (c,0)$ and $(x_2,y_2) = (-c,0)$
into Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ and simplify them to two polynomial equations in the unknown variables $x$ and $y.$
If you look at these carefully you should see a way to get an equation with only one unknown by combining the two equations.
That gives you the possible value(s) of one coordinate of your point, 
and you can use the equation of the ellipse to find the possible value(s) of the other coordinate.

---

As noted in a comment, you actually have *three* equations in $x$ and $y$: the original equation of the ellipse, and the two equations $(1)$ and $(2),$ which are equations of circles. The equations of the circles are just as good as the equation of the ellipse when you need to find the second coordinate; the ellipse and both circles all intersect at both of the solution points.

Comment: This is a good approach if the ellipse is centered at the origin and has major axis aligned with the $x$-axis.  But I took the Question to begin with an equation for an ellipse in general position (not necessarily axis aligned).

Comment: @hardmath "I have the standard equation of an ellipse with center at the origin"; also see Equation $(4)$ in the question.

Comment: I believe that you can use _any_ of the three equations to get the other coordinates. By construction, the intersection points of the two circles are also their intersections with the ellipse.

Comment: @amd Quite true. I think that's worth including in the answer, so I did so.